# Reject fileChooser from displaying internet resources like links etc

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

I would like to create a fileChooser, such that it only displays .csv files. For this purpose I created the follwing method:

```
private File openFileChooser() {
  FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
  fc.setTitle("Choose File");      
  fc.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
  fc.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("CSV", "*.csv"));   
  return fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);  
}
```

However, it still shows internet resources like links to webpages etc.. Is it possible to reject the fileChooser to also show such data types?

EDIT: My code sample was not correct. Thus I replaced

fc.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("CSV", ".csv"));   //old code sample

with

fc.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("CSV", "*.csv"));   //current code sample

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fc.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("CSV", "*.csv"));
```

Comment: ups... I did a little copy paste fault. Of course I already added "*.csv" and not ".csv". Will fix it in my post. Anyway, I am afraid this does not help me.

Comment: But this will only allow csv files, it won't reject lnk files, for example, and display everything else...

Comment: Well,this method usually works. So other file formats like .jpg, .pdf etc. are not shown. Only links to Websites are displayed additionally for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

From the limited testing I just did it seems you can't filter shortcuts (both filesystem or web shortcuts) from the FileChooser. I've tried using a regex to filter everything except starting with the letter "u", but it still lets the .url shortcuts through.